# how to raise event when there is change in oracle current redo log?

Tags: oracle, redo-logs

I have a requirement to read redo log files using logminer constantly and update the logminer results into a table.. Instead of scheduling a job for to reoccur at particular interval I am exploring ways to execute the job whenever new records are available in logminer or there is a change in redo log files.. was wondering that is there a way to raise an event whenever oracle redo log changes or whenever there are new rows read by logminer?

Thanks,
Ahmad

Comment: Why are you using LogMiner to read log data constantly?  What is the business problem you are trying to solve?  It would seem like Streams would be a much more appropriate architecture but, depending on the problem you're trying to solve, there might be a better approach.

Comment: need to build in house CDC app.. not sure about streams.. but logminer gives lot of control over the data...

Comment: I'm hard-pressed to believe that you wouldn't be better off using Streams or even Oracle's CDC for whatever you're trying to do rather than rolling your own solution starting all the way back from LogMiner.  Something like Streams also lets you read the online redo logs (depending on version, edition, and configuration) so that you're not constantly polling for log switches.